# How to add CDATA sections with transformers in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala, cdata, transformer-model

I'm trying to add CDATA sections around text in XML document with Scala transformer. I'm using the following transformer:

```
object AddCDATATransformer extends RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
    case n: Text => scala.xml.PCData(n.text)
    case _ => n
  }
}
```

but this does not work. The text is there but the CDATA section is not, i.e., I want to have `<![CDATA[text]]>` rather that `text`. Any ideas?

PS1. I googled out that there is some `-Xxml:coalescing` flag but cannot find any documentation on how to use it.

PS2. Strangely enough in another transformer I can produce CDATA sections with node copying:

```
n.copy(child = scala.xml.PCData(v) ++ n.child.tail)
```

Comment: _"this does not work"_ - HOW does it not work?

Comment: The text is there but the CDATA section is not, i.e., I want to have `<![CDATA[text]]>` rather that `text`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when posting questions on SO always be specific.  You'll get help a lot quicker that way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was trying to be as much specific I could. I've edited the post.